# BigQueryIO.write DynamicDestination withCreateDisposition - Clustering fields

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

BigQueryIO.write.withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED) along with DynamicDestinations we can write to the dynamic table and if the table does not exist it will create the table from TableSchema provided from DynamicDestinations.

I am not able to add clustering fields part of TableSchema model, because it does not have such a feature.

how we can add DynamicDestinations having TableSchema with clustering fields?

Answer (score 0):

bigQuery API is one way to add cluster field to a table

Using this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) you can test the API before writing your code

```
function execute() {
return gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.insert({
  "resource": {
    "configuration": {
      "query": {
        "clustering": {
          "fields": [
            "Field1",
            "Field2"
          ]
        },
        "query": "select 5",
        "destinationTable": {
          "datasetId": "Id1",
          "projectId": "Project1",
          "tableId": "T1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
    .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          },
          function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
```

}

And This is a JS example on how to manipulate the parameters:

```
static setConfiguration(params, configuration) {
    //To have a destination table we MUST have a tableId
    if (params.destinationTable && params.destinationTable.tableId) {
        configuration.query.destinationTable = params.destinationTable

    }
    if (params.clusteringFields) {
        configuration.query.clustering = {fields: params.clusteringFields}
    }
    if (params.timePartitioning) {
        configuration.query.timePartitioning = {
            type: 'DAY',
            field: params.timePartitioning
        }
    }
    if (params.writeDisposition) {
        configuration.query.writeDisposition = params.writeDisposition
    }
    if (params.queryPriority && params.queryPriority.toUpperCase() === "BATCH") {
        configuration.query.priority = "BATCH"
    }
    if (params.useCache === false) {
        configuration.query.useQueryCache = params.useCache
    }
    if (params.maxBillBytes) {
        configuration.query.maximumBytesBilled = params.maxBillBytes
    }
    if (params.maxBillTier) {
        configuration.query.maximumBillingTier = params.maxBillTier
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @tamir-klein . My question is more related to BigQueryIO.write with apache beam dataflow. The dymaic destination implements function/method for TableSchema and TableSchema does  not have feature for adding clustering.

Comment: Indeed after reading BigQueryIO. write in this link https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/ you will need to write your custom code for now. Note: Clustering is still in Beta mode

Answer (score 0):

Now after version 2.16.0, BigQueryIO does provide an option to add clusteringFields in dynamic destinations.

```
    @Override
    public TableDestination getTable(String eventName) {
        return new TableDestination(tableSpec,
                tableDescription, timePartitioning, clustering);
    }
```

Notice that the 4th parameter is **clustering**, which you can use.